# OpenCV video capture results

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am following along with a tutorial on OpenCV video capture and I am returning values I dont understand.  Here is my script:

```
import cv2, time

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

check, frame = video.read()

print(check)
print(frame)

time.sleep(3)
cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)

cvw.waitKey(0)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

When I run the script these are my results:

```
False
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capture.py", line 11, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

I dont know why I am returning 'False" and 'None".

Thank you for any help

Comment: You might be better off with this open-cv tutorial on video capture.    https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: @Mitch Please, update web link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need some delay before first reading.
Insert delay code like this

```
import time
#if you use camera
#video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#if you use video file
video=cv2.VideoCapture('c:/1.avi')
time.sleep(3)
check, frame = video.read()

print(check)
print(frame)
```

Comment: I still receive the same error message. The 'print(check)' command returns 'False' and the 'print(frame)' returns 'None'

Comment: if you are use camera, then use function 'cv2.VideoCapture(0)', if not, you should specify video file path

Comment: did you connect camera?

Comment: I didn't know I needed to connect the camera.  I am NEW to programming and this is my first venture into openCV

Comment: Pls connect usb cam or specify video file path. regards. would u check my answer?

Comment: I am trying to use a built in camera on my macbook to capture a new video

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to continuously read the frames from the camera.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    if frame.size != 0:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I still receive the same error message. The 'print(check)' command returns 'False' and the 'print(frame)' returns 'None'

Comment: The camera is the built-in one? Or any external camera?

Comment: armas- the camera is built in

Comment: I have added to check if the frame size is not zero. Please check the code. If there is no frame shown, then you need to check the camera functionality.